# Sample Azure Function in .NET 5 using IAsyncCollector<T>to write multiple messages to a service bus

Tags: azure-functions, .net-5, azure-servicebus-queues

Can someone provide a sample code for an Azure Function in .NET 5 that uses an IAsyncCollector to add multiple messages to a service bus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IAsyncCollector` is currently not supported with out-of-process / worker process SDK according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#bindings):

> Because .NET isolated projects run in a separate worker process, bindings can't take advantage of rich binding classes, such as ICollector, IAsyncCollector, and CloudBlockBlob. There's also no direct support for types inherited from underlying service SDKs, such as DocumentClient and BrokeredMessage. Instead, bindings rely on strings, arrays, and serializable types, such as plain old class objects (POCOs).

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#multiple-output-bindings) is not clear about how to achieve it. This [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/317#issuecomment-802335360) highlights that you can by having a dedicated class with the `ServiceBusOutput` attribute on a collection property to dispatch serialized multiple values as separate messages. For example:

```cs
[Function("OneToMany")]
public static DispatchedMessages Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue",
    Connection = "AzureServiceBus")] string myQueueItem,
    FunctionContext context)
{
    // Generate 5 messages
    var messages = new List<MyMessage>();
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        var message = new MyMessage { Value = $"Message #{i}" };
        messages.Add(message);
    }

    return new DispatchedMessages
    { 
        Messages = messages.Select(x => JsonSerializer.Serialize(x)) 
    };
}
```

Where each message would be of the type `MyMessage`:

```cs
class MyMessage
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And the function would return it as a `DispatchedMessages` type which has a property `Messages` that would represent all the messages that need to be sent out as serialized strings:

```cs
public class DispatchedMessages
{
    [ServiceBusOutput(queueOrTopicName: "dest", Connection = "AzureServiceBus")]
    public IEnumerable<string> Messages { get; set; }
}
```

Note that the connection string name is necessary as by default Functions SDK will try to use `AzureWebJobsServiceBus` connection string name.

Once the function is completed, there will be 5 messages in the `dest` queue, with JSON content of the serialized `MyMessage` messages.

[image: queue state]
[image: message body]